# disabled a submitt button c# asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, forms, button

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text))
{
    Button1.Enabled = false; 
}
else
{
    Button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Hi,
I have a form with 3 TextBoxes and I want the submit button doesn't send any data if any of them are empty,

I already use `RequiredFieldValidator` but how I can prevent user from submit until they filled all boxes

I tried the code above ^

Comment: use client side `javascript` or `jquery` to disable them..

Answer (score 0):

you need some client side javascript..

at its simplest...

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClientClick="return checkRequireds()" runat="server" Text="Button" />
 <script>
         function checkRequireds() {
             var textBox = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>');
             return !(textBox.value == 'undefined' || textBox.value == '')
         }
 </script>
```

**PS:** If you use the required field validator, you have already blocked the page from posting